# MinMax return mechanics. How does it work on this Shildt's code example?

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop

I am reading Java Shildt The Complete reference and I am wondering about one piece of code thats looks very simple, but I can't understand how it works.

```
// A generic interface example.
// A Min/Max interface.
interface MinMax<T extends Comparable<T>> {
T min();
T max();
}

// Now, implement MinMax
class MyClass<T extends Comparable<T>> implements MinMax<T> {
T[] vals;

MyClass(T[] o) {
    vals = o;
}

// Return the minimum value in vals.
public T min() {
    T v = vals[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < vals.length; i++)
        if (vals[i].compareTo(v) < 0) v = vals[i];
    return v;
}

// Return the maximum value in vals.
public T max() {
    T v = vals[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < vals.length; i++)
        if (vals[i].compareTo(v) > 0) v = vals[i];
    return v;
}
}

class GenIFDemo {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Integer inums[] = {3, 6, 2, 8, 6};
    Character chs[] = {'b', 'r', 'p', 'w'};
    MyClass<Integer> iob = new MyClass<Integer>(inums);
    MyClass<Character> cob = new MyClass<Character>(chs);
    System.out.println("Max value in inums: " + iob.max());
    System.out.println("Min value in inums: " + iob.min());
    System.out.println("Max value in chs: " + cob.max());
    System.out.println("Min value in chs: " + cob.min());
}
}
//The output is shown here:
//Max value in inums: 8
//Min value in inums: 2
//Max value in chs: w
//Min value in chs: b
```

I can't understand this one and its output:

```
// Return the maximum value in vals.
public T max() {
    T v = vals[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < vals.length; i++)
        if (vals[i].compareTo(v) > 0) v = vals[i];
    return v;
}
```

Why the output is 8, if according to the condition,
*vals[1].compareTo(vals[0])*(6>3) *> 0* is already true,

so v = 6, not 8.

I can't understand how it finds the max and min value here..

Could you please explain it? Thanks!

Comment: Because there's a loop in there. It will not stop after just one success - it will instead replace `val`, and do that check for every item contained in `vals`.

Comment: yes, but.. it can find the working condition with an item that is making condition true and it can be not the max one value

Comment: In this algorithm `v` is always the "max so far". For your case. it will be 6 until 8 is encountered. When that happens, `v` becomes 8 and doesn't change after, because no other item will suffice `v.compareTo(vals[i]) > 0` check.

Comment: thank you very much, now I understand. The problem was that I thought 'v' does always equal to 'vals[0]'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only for the iteration where `i=1`, `vals[1].compareTo(vals[0])` comparison is done, in which case `v=6`. Consider the case `i=3` for the given for-loop. Here `vals[3]`, which is `8`, is compared with the value of `v` (which is `6` since it was updated before). Since 8 is larger than 6, the value of v is updated to 8 in this iteration.

Comment: yeah, that sounds good, but, isn't the "v" always equals "vals[0]" ?
Or it changes according to the last max value?

Comment: No. During execution, `v` changes to vals[3] when i=3 during the for-loop iteration. So it does not always equal `vals[0]`. Hence it changes depending on whenever the condition `vals[i].compareTo(v)` is actually greater than `0` (which occurs two times, one when `v=6` and `v=8`)

Answer (score 1):

`v` holds the max value and starts with the first one.
The loop iterates over the remaining elements and sets the value to `v` if `vals[i].compareTo(v) > 0` (which means `vals[i]` is greater than `v`).

So not only the first two elements are compared.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html),

```
a.compareTo(b)
```

returns a positive value if and only if `a` is to be regarded strictly larger than `b`, which means that

```
// Return the maximum value in vals.
public T max() {
    T v = vals[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < vals.length; i++)
        if (vals[i].compareTo(v) > 0) v = vals[i];
    return v;
}
```

actually determines the maximum where `v` is the candidate for the maximum. If `vals[i].compareTo(v)` is larger than zero, this means that `v[i]` is larger that the candidate for the maximum. Consequently, `v` ist assigned `vals[i]`, as `vals[i]` is the new candidate for the maximum.

Comment: oh, thanks, that's clear now, I thought that only "vals[i]" is changing in loop and "v" is always equal "vals[0]"